# GKE uanble to pull public images from my personal Dockerhub repository - the same works on AKS

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy a test app on GKE with a public image from my personal dockerhub registry and the pods fail to deploy with `ImagePullBackOff` error. I am able to use the  same image on Azure K8s Service (AKS) and successfully create pods

On GKE When I describe the pod I see the below error:

```
Failed to pull image "registryName/myImageName": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/registryName/myImageName:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/registryName/myImageName:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/registryName/myImageName/manifests/latest": dial tcp 44.205.64.79:443: i/o timeout
```

I have tried with public images on my dockerhub registry and also tried with `imagePullSecrets` too - I still have the same error.

Here's my pod definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: testapp
  labels:
    name: testapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: testapp
    image: registryName/myImageName:latest
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "200m"
      limits:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
```

The GKE version is : `1.23.8-gke.1900`

I have also seen this question being asked a few times in the past - all of them suggest using registry credentials (which I tried though my images are public) or point to [issues from long ago](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119820482?pli=1)

Comment: Are you using a private cluster?

Comment: No, it is not a private cluster. It's able to pull official images - for instance nginx from Dockerhub.